# How to generate executable TPC-DS queries?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, benchmarking, tpc

I have downloaded the DSGEN tool from the TPC-DS web site and already generated the tables and loaded the data into Oracle XE.

I am using the following command to generate the `SQL statements` :

> dsqgen -input ..\query_templates\templates.lst -directory ..\query_templates -dialect oracle -scale 1

However, No matter how I adjust the command I always get this **error** message :

> ERROR: A query template list must be supplied using the INPUT option

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do the directory and file exist in those paths relative to where you're running the command from? I assume you are on Windows from the \ path separator; is it happy with the `-input` style of flags, or is it expecting `/input`?

Comment: @AlexPoole /input is the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do I generate queries for mysql. The available dialects are not compatible with mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you need to use `/` rather than `-` for the flags for the Windows executable:

```
dsqgen /input ..\query_templates\templates.lst /directory ..\query_templates
    /dialect oracle /scale 1
```